# regex to match strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a small, yet annoying problem with regex. The input string (C#) to parse is like the following:

```
( "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet" + "Maecenas fermentum commodo leo.", "aaa", 120 )
```

I want regex to match string between first " and before first comma that is after " so I want to find:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet" + "Maecenas fermentum commodo leo.
```

So far I came up with:

```
\(\s*?\"(.*?)\".*?\)
```

but the result is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't even look like it's trying to match up to any comma.

Did you maybe intend to match a comma after that second quote?

```
\(\s*?\"(.*?)\",.*?\)
```

You should also be careful of inputs such as

```
( "Lorem ipsum dolor\", sit amet" + "Maecenas fermentum commodo leo.", "aaa", 120 )
```

as funky things like that are hard to deal with using only regex.

Comment: Thank you, but what if input string is:
( "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet" + "Maecenas fermentum commodo leo." )
And I'd love to see solution that handles input as you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the separating comma optional:

```
\(\s*\"(.+?)(\",.*|\"\s*)\)
```